# Send a notification or alert when bash asks for input from user

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, notify-send

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. There is an alias in my `.bashrc` which uses `notify-send`:

```
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

I can append `alert` to other commands as `somecommand; alert` or `somecommand && alert` and get get a pop-up notification after `somecommand` finishes (successfully). It reminds me that the command I ran in a Terminal window which is now minimised or in a different workspace has finished executing.

But I want a similar alert when it waits for an input from the user instead of completion (e.g. Yes/No prompt). How can I do that?

Analogous solution using `notify-send` would be great, but other *relatively simple* alternative would also be fine.

In case there's a confusion, I'm not planning to create an automated reply to the prompt. I just want it to remind me of forgotten (minimised/in different workspace) Terminal windows while running commands with lengthy output which may ask for user-input (e.g. `apt update && apt upgrade`).

Comment: Why not send the alert just before the `read` command?

Comment: @RudiC Could you please expand your comment (to an answer perhaps, I'm not good at bash scripting)? In case there's a confusion, I'm not not planning to create an automated reply to the prompt. I just want it to remind me of *forgotten* (minimised/in different workspace) Terminal window while running commands with *lengthy* output which may ask for user-input (e.g. `apt update && apt upgrade`).

Comment: Sounds like you DON'T have access to the scripts / commands, so CAN'T modify them, and want to be informed whenever any waits inside for a user interaction?

Comment: @RudiC Exactly! Is that impossible to achieve?

Comment: Can't tell from the top of my head. No simple approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Monitoring the dialogue of a program and send an alert

You can monitor the activity of

1. a **[fifo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))** or
2. an **`xterm` log file**, now with an interactive mode

and let it start a **`zenity` info message**, when there is input from the monitored program. If you wish, you can also install **`espeak`** and let it send an **audio message**.

#### 1. Start a `zenity` info message, when there is input from a monitored program using a fifo.

The following shellscript can monitor the output dialogue from a program and send an alert.

- assuming a graphical desktop environment
- start a wrapper shellscript in a terminal window, which is used like a 'console' for `wrapper`
- starting the program to be monitored in an `xterm` window
- **running the dialogue in the `xterm` window** (that is where you write your input)
- using a fifo to get access to the output of the program to be monitored, `/dev/stdout` and `dev/stderr`.
- running a `while` loop

  - testing if the fifo has been modified and in that case

    - starting a `zenity` info message window.

You are expected to close the `zenity` window (can work with 'Enter') to get back to the `xterm` window, where you write your input.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "'$0' is a wrapper, that sends a notification, when the wrapped program
has written to standard input and standard error and may be waiting for input.
---
Usage:   $0 <program name> [parameters]
Example: $0 .program"
 exit
fi

message="'${1##*/} $2 ...' has written something, maybe asks for input"

tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
tmpfifo=$(mktemp --tmpdir=$tmpdir)
rm "$tmpfifo"
mkfifo "$tmpfifo"
#ls -l "$tmpdir"
cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$tmpfifo")
sleep 1

xterm -title "${1##*/} $2 ..." -fa default -fs 11 -bg '#403600' \
 -e bash -c "$* 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr 2>&1 > $tmpfifo" 2> /dev/null & pid=$!

#< "$tmpfifo" espeak &
< "$tmpfifo" cat &

cont=true
while $cont
do
 tmpstr=$(ps -Af |sed "s/grep $pid//"|grep "$pid")
# echo "$tmpstr"
 if [ "$tmpstr" != "" ]
 then
  cnt0=$cnt1
  cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$tmpfifo")
  if [ "$cnt1" != "$cnt0" ]
  then
#   zenity --notification --text="$message" 2> /dev/null
#   espeak "$message" &
   zenity --info --title="${0##*/} ${1##*/} $2 ..." \
    --text="$message" --width=500  2> /dev/null
  fi
  sleep 1
  else
  sleep .2
  # echo "process $pid has finished"
  cont=false
 fi
done

# clean up

rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

You may wish to run `espeak` near `zenity` to get an audio message too. In that case you can remove the `#` character in the beginning of that line. (There may be a lot of text from the program, so it is usually a bad idea to redirect the fifo to `espeak`. It is better to redirect the fifo to `cat` and have it printed in the 'console'.)

### Demo

You can test some command lines with `cp -i` and `mv -i` and you can test with the following little shellscript `program`,

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
 read -p "Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit " string
 if [ "${string:0:4}" == "Stop" ]
 then
  printf "$string. Gotcha\n"
  break
 elif [ "$string" != "" ]
 then
  printf "$string\n"
  printf "Working for 10 seconds ...\n"
  sleep 10
 else 
  sleep 3
 fi
done
```

**Help text:**

```
$ ./wrapper
'./wrapper' is a wrapper, that sends a notification, when the wrapped program
has written to standard input and standard error and may be waiting for input.
---
Usage:   ./wrapper <program name> [parameters]
Example: ./wrapper .program
```

**Monitoring `program`:**

```
$ ./wrapper ./program
```

`zenity` info message window:

[image]

Dialogue in the `xterm` window:

```
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Hello
Hello
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit World
World
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Goodbye
Goodbye
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Stop
```

'Console' output in the original terminal window after finishing:

```
$ ./wrapper ./program
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Hello
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit World
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Goodbye
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Stop. Gotcha
```

**Monitoring `cp -ip`:**

```
$ LANG=C /path/wrapper cp -ip ubuntustudio-18.04-dvd-amd64.iso ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso /tmp
```

`zenity` info message window:

[image]

Dialogue in `xterm`:

```
cp: overwrite '/tmp/ubuntustudio-18.04-dvd-amd64.iso'? y
cp: overwrite '/tmp/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'? n
```

**Monitoring `sudo parted /dev/sdc`:**

```
$ LANG=C ./wrapper sudo parted /dev/sdc
```

Dialogue in `xterm`:

```
[sudo] password for sudodus: 
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Model: SanDisk Extreme (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 16,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 3      2097kB  258MB   256MB   primary   fat32        boot
 4      258MB   1366MB  1108MB  primary
 2      1366MB  12,4GB  11,0GB  extended               lba
 5      1367MB  6736MB  5369MB  logical   ext2
 6      6737MB  12,4GB  5615MB  logical   ext4
 1      12,4GB  16,0GB  3662MB  primary   ntfs

(parted) q
```

#### 2. Start a `zenity` info message, when something is written to an `xterm` window (from the monitored program or from the user).

The following shellscript can monitor the dialogue with a program and send an alert.

- assuming a graphical desktop environment
- start a wrapper shellscript in a terminal window, which is used like a 'console' for `wrapper`
- starting the program to be monitored in an `xterm` window
- **running the dialogue in the `xterm` window** (that is where you write your input)
- using a log file of `xterm` to get access to the output from and input to the program to be monitored
- running a `while` loop

  - testing if the log file has been modified and in that case

    - starting a `zenity` info message window.
    - short delays are allowed during typing the input (8 seconds; you can edit the script file to change the delay time).

You are expected to close the `zenity` window (can work with 'Enter') to get back to the `xterm` window, where you write your input.

**Now there is an interactive mode, where you use the `xterm` window just as you use any terminal window.** Close the `xterm` window to stop monitoring.

```
#!/bin/bash

# date        editor   comment
# 2018-12-31  sudodus  version 1.0

version=1.0

name="${0##*/}"
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]
then
 echo "'$name' is a wrapper, that sends a notification, when the wrapped program
has written to standard input and standard error and may be waiting for input.
---
Usage:    $name [program name] [parameters]
Examples: $name          # to run program(s) interactively in an xterm window
          $name program
          $name -h       # to get help (this text)
          $name -v       # show version"
 exit
elif [ "$1" == "-v" ]
then
 echo "$name version $version"
 exit
fi
tstart=$(date '+%s')
echo "----- start $name at $(date '+%F %T') ----------------------------"
tmpstr="${1##*/}"
xtermlog=$(mktemp -u)

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
 mess_zenity="Check, if the monitored program asks for input"
 mess_espeak="${mess_zenity/program/, Program,}"
 xterm -title "monitored by ${0##*/}" -fa default -fs 11 -bg '#2c2b2a' \
 -l -lf "$xtermlog" -sb -rightbar 2> /dev/null & pid=$!
else
 mess_espeak="Check if '${tmpstr^} ${2##*/} ${3##*/} ...' asks for input"
 mess_zenity="Check if '$tmpstr $2 $3 ...' asks for input"
 xterm -title "${1##*/} $2 $3 ..." -fa default -fs 11 -bg '#2c2b2a' \
 -l -lf "$xtermlog" -e "$@" 2> /dev/null & pid=$!
fi
sleep 0.5
sync
cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$xtermlog")
tail -f "$xtermlog" & ptail=$!

cont=true
while $cont
do
 sleep 1
 cnt0=$cnt1
 tmpstr=$(ps -Af |sed "s/grep $pid//"|grep "$pid")
# echo "$tmpstr"
 if [ "$tmpstr" != "" ]
 then
  cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$xtermlog")
  if [ $cnt1 -gt $((cnt0 + 8)) ]
  then
#   zenity --notification --text="$message" 2> /dev/null
   espeak "$mess_espeak" &
   zenity --info --title="${0##*/} ${1##*/} $2 ..." \
    --text="$mess_zenity" --width=500  2> /dev/null
   touch "$xtermlog"
   cnt1=$(stat --printf "%Y" "$xtermlog")
  fi
  sleep 1
  else
  sleep .2
  # echo "process $pid has finished"
  cont=false
 fi
done

# clean up
tmpstr="$(tail -n1 "$xtermlog" | sed 's/.*exit.*/exit/')"
if [ "$tmpstr" != "exit" ]
then
 echo ""
fi
rm -r "$xtermlog"
kill $ptail
tend=$(date '+%s')
tuse=$((tend-tstart))
echo "------- end $name at $(date '+%F %T') --- used $tuse seconds"
```

Save thís `bash` code to a file and give it [for example] the name `vialog`, make it executable and maybe move it to a directory in your path.

```
$ vialog
----- start vialog at 2018-12-31 14:37:41 ----------------------------
```

You work in the `xterm` window and the dialogue is echoed to the starting window too.

[image]

```
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/pomsky-wrap $ ./program
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Hello World
Hello World
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit I am writing ...
I am writing ...
Working for 10 seconds ...
Waiting for input. 'Stop' to Quit Stop
Stop. Gotcha
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/pomsky-wrap $ scrot -sb
sudodus@bionic64 /media/multimed-2/test/test0/pomsky-wrap $ exit
exit
------- end vialog at 2018-12-31 14:39:02 --- used 81 seconds
```

[image]

Comment: @pomsky, I enjoy working on solutions to your problem. Please let me know if any of the edited shellscripts can do what you want, and if not, what it should do (how to improve it).

Comment: See also this link [Wake me up when a slow command line process wants my attention?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention/1106780#1106780)

Comment: @pomsky, I'm glad these methods are useful for you :-) Have a look also at the fifo method using the compiled program `script` in my thread at AskUbuntu (linked in my previous comment). Please tell me which of the methods, that works best for you, so that I can focus on that method.

Answer (score 1):

### Invitation to feedback

Instead of adding another shellscript to my already existing answer, I think it is better with a second answer. I will listen to feedback and focus on the preferred script/method and try to merge what is preferred into one answer (unless there are reasons to keep them all (for different purposes).

### Monitoring the dialogue of a program and send an alert

You can monitor the activity of

1. a **[fifo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))** or
2. an **`xterm` log file**

and let it start a **`zenity` info message**, when there is input from the monitored program. If you wish, you can also install **`espeak`** and let it send an **audio message**.

This answer focuses on a second alternative using a **fifo**.

#### Start a `zenity` info message, when there is input from a monitored program using a fifo.

#### 1.1 Using `xterm`, monitoring standard output and standard error via a fifo

This `wrapper` method has the

- **advantage**, that no direct input will trigger the alert. This works well with many programs, for example `cp -i` and `sudo`.
- **disadvantage**, that

  - some programs will be disabled, because they use not only standard output and standard error for writing its output. Example: `sftp` will lose the prompt, and the user cannot know, when the program is ready for a new task.
  - some programs echo the input (there is indirect input), and this will trigger the alert, which may cause a lot of alerts in a shellscript, that does not take that into account. Example: `ssh`.

#### 1.2 Using the compiled program `script` and its log file via a fifo

The following shellscript can monitor the output dialogue from a program and send an alert. It needs `espeak` and `script` (`script` need not be installed in Ubuntu and Debian).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install espeak
```

- assuming a graphical desktop environment
- start a shellscript in a terminal window, let us call it **`viafifo`**.
- starting the program to be monitored 'in `viafifo`'
- **running the dialogue in the terminal window** (that is where you write your input)
- using a fifo to get access to the output of the program to be monitored, `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout` and `dev/stderr`. The main task in the shellscript is the line with the program **`script`**, that is monitoring the activity in the terminal window and writing to the fifo.
- running a `while` loop

  - testing if the fifo has been modified and in that case

    - starting a `zenity` info message window and a correspoding spoken message with `espeak`.
    - short delays are allowed during typing the input (8 seconds; you can edit the script file to change the delay time).

You are expected to close the `zenity` window (can work with 'Enter') to get back to the `xterm` window, where you write your input.

Type `exit` to leave `script` and `viafifo`. After that you can get a log file with the whole dialogue.

`viafifo` is tested with

- [**Ubuntu** 18.04.1 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention/1106780#1106780). [<kbd>**<---**</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention/1106780#1106780) You find the **bash code** of `viafifo` in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention/1106780#1106780).
- **Debian** 9.6.0, 'Stretch'. See the following screenshots and printout of `time viafifo` and `viafifo.log`.

#### Demo example

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

**`time viafifo`**

```
user@debian:~$ time viafifo
----- Start viafifo ------------------------------------------------------------
user@debian:~$ echo hello
hello
user@debian:~$ exit
exit
----- End viafifo --------------------------------------------------------------
See 'viafifo.log'
viafifo used 8 seconds plus a few (5-10) seconds for preparing and finishing
real    0m13.295s
user    0m0.104s
sys 0m0.012s
```

**`viafifo.log`**

```
user@debian:~$ cat viafifo.log
Script started on Sat 05 Jan 2019 07:57:45 PM UTC
user@debian:~$ echo hello
hello
user@debian:~$ exit
exit
viafifo used 8 seconds
user@debian:~$
```