# Capture output of a command, process it and ONLY then output to terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, stdout, hook

I would like to capture the stdout (as sent to a terminal), and perform some processing after it is output on the terminal (for the user).

I want to know how to grab the output, process and make changes accordingly.

(If possible) I want this to happen for every command I type on the terminal.

---

Edit: After a dialogue in a temporary chat forum it was clear that

- we should

  - both look for which commands are issued
  - and what output there is from the commands and
- do something, if a particular command or output is detected.

Comment: does the other script have output, and if so, where should *it* go?

Comment: No, it does not have any output. For now it just checks the size of stdout.

Comment: It is not clear, what you are asking to do. I get that you want to process stdout, of a process. Do you want the output of the process to go to the screen, do you want the unprocessed data to go to the screen, … (Please amend question to make clear -1 for now)

Comment: I think we made it clear in the chat forum (linked to after my answer) :-)

Comment: I realized that it can be done even after the ouput is visible to the user. @sudodus, helped me out in the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe it is *not* a good idea to grab the output, process and display the output of *every* command you type on the terminal.

But you can do it for some particular command via `tee`

```
your-command | tee saved-output | processing-tool
```

When you have seen the result from the processing-tool, you can look at the `saved-output` for example with `cat` (if short output) or `less` (if long output).

Example:

```
$ LANG=C sudo lshw | tee saved-output | grep -i -A2 disk
        *-disk              
             description: ATA Disk
             product: KINGSTON SKC300S
             physical id: 0.0.0
--
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD4002FYYZ-0
             vendor: Western Digital
$ less saved-output
```

---

After a dialogue in a temporary chat forum , I suggest to

- try `vialog` or `viafifo` according to the following links
- maybe modify one of them to do what is expected in this case,

  - both look for which commands are issued
  - and what output there is from the commands and
- do something, if a particular command or output is detected.
- [Send a notification or alert when bash asks for input from user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491121/send-a-notification-or-alert-when-bash-asks-for-input-from-user/491248#491248)
- [This link to AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention/1106780#1106780)

It works directly to use `vialog` like the following example.

```
vialog 2>&1 | tee saved-output | grep 'docker container ls' && echo 'it was mentioned'
```

In the real case, I think you would like to start something more advanced than `echo 'it was mentioned'`, but this is only a demo example. And things can be more efficient, if you build the specific checks into `vialog` and disable the alerts, that are probably not necessary in your case.

Screenshot during the dialogue:

[image]

Screenshot after the dialogue:

[image]

This way you can easily check if a command that is called is not found:

```
$ LANGUAGE=C vialog 2>&1 | tee saved-output | grep -i 'Command.*not found' && echo 'it was mentioned'
Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:
it was mentioned
$ cat saved-output 
----- start vialog at 2019-01-12 18:57:33 ----------------------------
$ docker container ls

Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install docker.io

$ exit
exit
------- end vialog at 2019-01-12 18:58:01 --- used 28 seconds
```

Comment: Or to put it very simply, is it possible to run a script after every command, even after outputting it to the terminal.Does something like a post-command hook exist ?

Comment: @100rabh, *Why do you want this?* But yes, almost everything is possible with linux. For example, you can call a subshell, that runs your command and does the post-processing before it returns.

Comment: To further simplify, I want to check if a specific command is being executed and based on that run a shell script or a python file.

Comment: @100rabh, Do you want to check for a particular text string in the output from the specific command, or do you want to check if there is a particular process during the execution of the specific command, or something else?

Comment: @100rabh, This may be an x/y problem. Please tell us in very general terms what you want, and I or more likely someone else can suggest a method to get what you want.

Comment: I want to check if a command say "docker container ls" is input in the terminal.
So only if the above command is inputted to the terminal then do something or else do nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88176/discussion-between-sudodus-and-100rabh).